# setState() within StatefulWidget not working properly

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

The thing I'm trying to do is, to change the colour of a `RawMaterialButton` when the button is clicked. Read about `StatefulWidget` and it seemed like it should work, but for some reason it doesn't.

`flutter: Another exception was thrown: setState() called in constructor: ButtonTest#1a93b(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)`

ButtonTest class:

```
class ButtonState extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => ButtonTest();
}

class ButtonTest extends State<ButtonState> implements Cipher {
  @override
  String icon = '';

  @override
  String title = '';

  bool enabled = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(this.title),
      ),
      body: RawMaterialButton(
          shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
          fillColor: enabled ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              this.enabled = true;
            });
          },
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0)),
    );
  }
}
```

Cipher class:

```
abstract class Cipher {
  String icon;
  String title;
  Widget build(BuildContext context);
}
```

getCiphers()

```
getCiphers() {
  final List<Cipher> ciphers = new List();

  ciphers.add(ButtonTest());
  return ciphers;
}
```

Main class:

```
void main() => runApp(CipherTools());

class CipherTools extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'CipherTools',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CipherScreen(
        ciphers: getCiphers(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CipherScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Cipher> ciphers;

  CipherScreen({Key key, @required this.ciphers}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Ciphers'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: ciphers.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(ciphers[index].title),
            // When a user taps on the ListTile, navigate to the DetailScreen.
            // Notice that we're not only creating a DetailScreen, we're
            // also passing the current todo through to it!
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailScreen(cipher: ciphers[index]),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Todo
  final Cipher cipher;

  // In the constructor, require a Todo
  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.cipher}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return cipher.build(context);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap setState() like this.

```
 if(this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
          this.enabled = true;
        });
 }
```

Comment: please follow the link -> https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- `ButtonState` should be called `ButtonTest` because this is the
  `StatefulWidget`
- `ButtonTest` should be called `ButtonTestState` because this is the `State`.

Then in `DetailScreen`, in the `build()` method, you could return the `StatefulWidget` (`ButtonTest`), like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ButtonTest();
}
```